# Retrieving image height with CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I need the ability to put the processed image's dimensions.

I have in my `ImageUploader` class:

```
version :post do
  process :resize_to_fit => [200, nil]
end
```

Is there a way that I could get the image's dimensions similar to this?

```
height = @picture.image_height(:post)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can adjust and use the method described here: http://code.dblock.org/carrierwave-saving-best-image-geometry

It adds a process then call Magick's method to fetch image geometry.

Code:

```
  version :post do
    process :resize_to_fit => [200, nil]
    process :get_geometry

    def geometry
      @geometry
    end
  end

  def get_geometry
    if (@file)
      img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first
      @geometry = [ img.columns, img.rows ]
    end
  end
```

Comment: +1 This method is a lot cleaner and is similar to the one recommended by RMagick here: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/comtasks.html

Comment: I am not sure about this here, but let me recommend .ping instead of .read (from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16267106/4738391)

Answer (score 7):

You can hook onto the :cache and :retrieve_from_cache methods

There is no need to rely on system commands either:

```
# Somewhere in your uploader:
attr_reader :geometry
after :cache, :capture_size
after :retrieve_from_cache, :capture_size
def capture_size(*args)    
  img = ::MiniMagick::Image::read(File.binread(@file.file))
  @geometry = [img[:width], img[:height]]
end
```

http://www.glebm.com/2012/05/carrierwave-image-dimensions.html

Comment: Thanks! The the solution marked as the answer didn't work for me. Nice & simple solution.

Comment: Please note that this will only capture the biggest version's size. You can use https://github.com/gzigzigzeo/carrierwave-meta for multiple version support (it adds process like the other examples). Also this is probably not very efficient since I seem to be using `binread` here, which reads the whole file instead of just the header

Answer (score 1):

i googled some around a came onto a post with the following:

source link http://groups.google.com/group/carrierwave/browse_thread/thread/c5e93b45bde8a85e?fwc=1&pli=1

```
class HeaderUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base 
   storage :right_s3 
  def store_dir 
     "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}" 
  end 
  def url 
    ["http://#{s3_bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/", path].compact.join 
  end 
   before :cache, :capture_size_before_cache 
   before :retrieve_from_cache, :capture_size_after_retrieve_from_cache 
  def capture_size_before_cache(new_file) 
    model.header_width, model.header_height = `identify -format "%wx 
 %h" #{new_file.path}`.split(/x/) 
  end 
  def capture_size_after_retrieve_from_cache(cache_name) 
    model.header_width, model.header_height = `identify -format "%wx 
%h" #...@file.path}`.split(/x/) 
  end 
  def dimensions 
    "#{model.header_width}x#{model.header_height}" 
  end 
end
```