# RMagick - how do I find out the pixel dimension of an image

Tags: ruby, rmagick

How does one find the image width and height in pixels?

`image.x_resolution` and `image.y_resolution` both return 0 for some reason.

Comment: `x_resolution` and `y_resolution` are properties to do with output devices - e.g. pixels-per-inch.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
require 'rmagick'
img = Magick::Image.ping( 'demo.png' ).first
width = img.columns
height = img.rows
```

Note `.ping` method imported from comments. If you need to read the image to process it, then use `Magick::Image.read( 'demo.png' ).first` - the use of `ping` works in this stand-alone code and speeds processing up for some image types where IM can just read a header block. This is useful for cases where you don't need to load the image itself to do work on it.

Comment: If you are only interested in the image metadata, but don't care about the pixel data, you should use `ping` instead of `read`. See [the doc page](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#ping)

Comment: Slightly cleaner imo: `img = Magick::Image.read('demo.png')[0]; width, height = image.columns, image.rows`

Comment: @mahemoff: Edited to remove extra `[0]`s. Answer is really about the slightly obscure method names `columns` and `rows` . . . totally up to you how you want to use them.

Comment: Indeed, it's a side issue. I just find the idiom of width, height cleaner here, but hey it's Ruby - timtowtdi

Comment: Just my 2c here - I'm dubious about the claim that this only reads part of the header block in order to report this data. I base this on a customer experience loading 16 images, each JPG, and the time taken to "ping" ranged from 0.023s up to 1.25s - if only a small header was being read, one would expect this to be a lot more consistent, and definitely less that 1.25s

Comment: @Nathan: It may depend on the file format, and JPEG support for the header info in a convenient part of the file may be optional - decided at the time the file was written.  If you are getting 1.25s to read a file (which presumably was <100MB even if the whole file was being read) from any modern storage system, then likely something else is wrong in any case.

Comment: How to get these info when using the R package? The object I get from `image_read` seems like a damn black box, but the properties are displayed in the description!!!!

Comment: @Andry: This answer is for Ruby. If you cannot find this question answered for R, then you might like to ask a new question on the site.

Comment: @NeilSlater yep... just for the record... function ‘image_info’ should be used 

Answer (score -3):

You can get the image dimensions from img.inspect - instructions included at http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html

An example would be

```
 f.inspect » "images/Flower_Hat.jpg JPEG 200x250 DirectClass 8-bit 9kb"
```

Comment: The op specifically asked for Rmagick and you gave answer for ImageMagick. Although s/he can figure out the answer from it, this is not the way you should answer a question.