# Accessing to an image instance with carrierwave and fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, fog

I'm trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584433/895789) to get the dimensions of an image. In development works great, but in staging (using fog) with `img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first` throws me:
`private method 'file' called for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000008fe28d0>`

How can I retrieve the file with fog?

**Update:**

I'm using `carrirwave_backgrounder` to process the images asynchronously. This is part of the code:

```
# the uploader
def geometry
  @geometry ||= get_geometry
end

def get_geometry
  if(@file)
    img = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(@file.file)
    @geometry = {width: img[:width], height: img[:height]}
  end
end

# the model
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
process_in_background :image
before_save :set_dimensions


def set_dimensions
  geometry = self.image.geometry
  self.width = geometry[:width]
  self.height = geometry[:height]
end
```

I've figured out that the error appears just when I update the model, not when this is created, so I've changed the callback to `before_create :set_dimensions` and works fine. I suppose it could be because when I'm updating, the file is just in the assets host, but is just a guessing.

Comment: Weird work out of box for me everytime Can u paste uploader code

Comment: @Viren I've solved the issue in some way, but anyways check the updated question. Thanks

Comment: If it was `after_save` it will not work because preprocessing hapeen `before` save because in `after_save` u you would `@file` instance as `fog` instead of `CarrierWave:SantizedFile`

Comment: @Viren I never said that I used `after_save`. At first I used `before_save` and after that I changed to `before_create`. The error happened just when I updated to record, not to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `file` for `url`, so it will be:

```
img = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(@file.url)
```